# Switch to a specific tab having it's title using .SwitchToWindowByName method

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an Excel macro in which I want to check if a specific Chrome tab is open (with it's title).

`chromeBrowser.SwitchToWindowByName` generates

> Application-defined or object-defined error

```vb
Public Sub searchChromeTabs()

Dim chromeBrowser As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Set chromeBrowser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

chromeBrowser.SetCapability "debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222"
chromeBrowser.Start

chromeBrowser.SwitchToWindowByName("(Tab name which I want to switch to and do rest of my code in it)")
'And this is the place which throws an Application-defined or object-defined error.
  
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: **Application-defined or object-defined** error